# State/Province conditions not working on any of my rules

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.2.2, magento-2.0

Any time I include a state/province condition on any cart rule the condition is totally ignored. Every other conditions is taken into account and working accept the state/province conditions. Can anyone help?

Comment: your question is quite not clear, explain briefly with code and effort, remove unused tags from your question, keep only which you used Magento version for the better search to others

Comment: @Hit's it's pretty clear. Whenever I have an active coupon or any shipping rule.... the rule ignores any state/province condition.